# rsyslog high performance: get maximum message per second

Tags: performance, rsyslog, rate

I'd like to optimize rsyslog in order to have a maximum amount of messages per second.

I work with The rsyslog 8.27.0. With my current configuration ,it offers me about 72k messages /second.

Do you have any other configuration to get my goal ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you done to determine what's actually limiting your performance?

Comment: @AndrewHenle : Main Queue configuration: 
main_queue( queue.type="LinkedList"  queue.size="1000000"  queue.debatchsize="4096"  queue.workerthreads="4"   queue.workerThreadMinimumMessages = "250000")
Filter && Action Queue: input(type="imfile" File="/mnt/resource/testrsyslog.log"  Tag="rsys-test-log"  Facility="local1" ruleset="writeRemoteData")
ruleset(name="writeRemoteData"  queue.type="LinkedList" queue.size="1000000" queue.dequeueBatchSize="4096" queue.workerThreads="8" queue.workerThreadMinimumMessages="250000") {
    action(type="omfile" file=".." asyncWriting="on")
}

Comment: Posting the configuration has nothing to do with identifying performance bottlenecks on your system.  What *testing* have you done to identify your performance bottlenecks?  Have you profiled your `rsyslogd` daemon?  Have you varied the types and sizes of messages sent?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, For my test i have followed this tuto http://www.rsyslog.com/tag/syslog_caller/ . For the last 2 questions, i don't know how to do it. Do you have a tuto for that ? Thanks in advance